# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') when trying to display two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a component containing an array, which has certain categories and headers. I wanted to put these into a collapsible menu, but ran into trouble because since all the items are in a single array, I only had the option of toggling every item, so my solution was to split up the array into two, so I could seperate the categories for toggling, but when doing so I am getting the following error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')"

Here I will show you the code and where the error occurs.

So this is my array. As you can see I have mainLinkGroups and mainLinkGroupsTwo that I pass to my tools menu component.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <tools-menu ref="toolsMenu" :main-link-groups="mainLinkGroups"/>
    <tools-menu ref="toolsMenu" :main-link-groups-two="mainLinkGroupsTwo"/>
      </div>
</template>

<script>
  import icons from '@/models/entity/icon';
  import ToolsMenu from '@/components/navbar/ToolsMenu';
  
  export default {
    components: {
      ToolsMenu,
          },

    computed: {
      mainLinkGroups() {
        return [
          {
            header: 'HeaderOne',
            icon: icons.HOME,
            links:   [
              {
                icon: 'fas fa-copy',
                text: 'Foo',
                area: 'ONE'
              }       
                    ]
      },
      mainLinkGroupsTwo() {
        return [
          {
            header: 'HeaderTwo',
            links:  [
              {
                to: '/home',
                icon: 'fas fa-home',
                text: 'home',
                area: 'TWO'
              },
                   ]
      }
    },
    methods: {
      showTools() {
        this.$refs.toolsMenu.show();
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

And here is the tools menu component. The error occurs here:

```js
filteredLinkGroups() {
        return this.mainLinkGroups.map(linkGroup => ({header: linkGroup.header, links: linkGroup.links.filter(item => {
            const userAreaPermission = this.userAreaPermissionMap[item.area];
            return !item.area || userAreaPermission &&
              (item.modal ? userAreaPermission === 'FULL_CONTROL' : userAreaPermission !== 'NOT_ALLOWED');
          })}));

filteredLinkGroupsTwo() {
        return this.mainLinkGroups.map(linkGroup => ({header: linkGroup.header, links: linkGroup.links.filter(item => {
            const userAreaPermission = this.userAreaPermissionMap[item.area];
            return !item.area || userAreaPermission &&
              (item.modal ? userAreaPermission === 'FULL_CONTROL' : userAreaPermission !== 'NOT_ALLOWED');
          })}));
```

If I remove filteredLinkGroupsTwo, then I don't get the error, but I need it to display my array. Why does having a duplicate of this function cause the error. They don't have the same names, just the same function.

The full code:

```js
<template>
  <b-modal
    id="tools-modal"
    v-model="visible"
    modal-class="main-menu-modal"
    size="lg"
    :hide-footer="small"
    @show="refreshNodes"
    scrollable
    hide-header
  >
    <b-row class="h-100">
      <b-col class="h-100" >

     
          <template v-for="(linkGroup, index) in filteredLinkGroups">
            <b-col v-b-toggle.collapse2  class="group-header">
              <div class="header-icon" v-if="linkGroup.header.includes('HeaderOne')">
                <i class="fas fa-list fa-lg"></i>
              </div>
              <h4 class="header-title">{{$t(linkGroup.header)}}</h4>
            </b-col>
            <b-collapse id="collapse1">
            <b-row cols="3" cols-sm="4" cols-lg="4" @click="visible = false" no-gutters>
              <b-col v-for="link in linkGroup.links" style="padding: 0 1rem 1rem;">
                <b-link :to="link.to" @click="clickLink(link)">
                  <b-aspect>
                    <b-card body-class="text-center d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center" id="menu-card">
                      <div><i class="fa-fw fa-xl" :class="link.icon"/></div>
                      <div style="line-height: 1.5em; min-height: 3em;" class="d-flex align-items-center">{{ $t(link.text) }}</div>
                    </b-card>
                  </b-aspect>
                </b-link>
              </b-col>
            </b-row>
            </b-collapse>
          </template>

          <template v-for="(linkGroup, index) in filteredLinkGroupsTwo">
            <b-col v-b-toggle.collapse3  class="group-header">
              <div class="header-icon" v-if="linkGroup.header.includes('HeaderTwo')">
                <i class="fas fa-building fa-lg"></i>
              </div>
              <h4 class="header-title">{{$t(linkGroup.header)}}</h4>
            </b-col>
            <b-collapse id="collapse4">
              <b-row cols="3" cols-sm="4" cols-lg="4" @click="visible = false" no-gutters>
                <b-col v-for="link in linkGroup.links" style="padding: 0 1rem 1rem;">
                  <b-link :to="link.to" @click="clickLink(link)">
                    <b-aspect>
                      <b-card body-class="text-center d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center" id="menu-card">
                        <div><i class="fa-fw fa-xl" :class="link.icon"/></div>
                        <div style="line-height: 1.5em; min-height: 3em;" class="d-flex align-items-center">{{ $t(link.text) }}</div>
                      </b-card>
                    </b-aspect>
                  </b-link>
                </b-col>
              </b-row>
            </b-collapse>
          </template>
      </b-col>
    </b-row>
  </b-modal>
</template>

<script>
  import icons from '@/models/entity/icon';
  import utils from '@/utils/utils';
  import {mainMenuService} from '@/services/areas/main-menu';
  import {userService} from '@/services/user';
  import LoadingMessage from '@/components/LoadingMessage';
  import {EventBus, Events} from '@/utils/event-bus';
  import {systemService} from '@/services/system';

  const urlMap = {
    COMPANY: 'companies',
    PROPERTY_OWNER: 'property-owners',
    PROPERTY: 'properties',
    UNIT: 'units',
    TENANCY: 'tenancies'
  };


  export default {
    components: {
      LoadingMessage,
    },
    props: {
      mainLinkGroups: Array,
      mainLinkGroupsTwo: Array
    },
    data() {
      return {
        icons,
        pageHistory: [],
        breadcrumb: null,
        visible: false,
        nodes: null,
        userNavigationSettings: null,
        userAreaPermissionMap: {},
      };
    },
    computed: {
      small() {
        return ['xs', 'sm', 'md'].includes(this.$mq);
      },
      filteredLinkGroups() {
        return this.mainLinkGroups.map(linkGroup => ({header: linkGroup.header, links: linkGroup.links.filter(item => {
            const userAreaPermission = this.userAreaPermissionMap[item.area];
            return !item.area || userAreaPermission &&
              (item.modal ? userAreaPermission === 'FULL_CONTROL' : userAreaPermission !== 'NOT_ALLOWED');
          })}));
      },
      filteredLinkGroupsTwo() {
        return this.mainLinkGroupsTwo.map(linkGroup => ({header: linkGroup.header, links: linkGroup.links.filter(item => {
            const userAreaPermission = this.userAreaPermissionMap[item.area];
            return !item.area || userAreaPermission &&
                (item.modal ? userAreaPermission === 'FULL_CONTROL' : userAreaPermission !== 'NOT_ALLOWED');
          })}));
      },
    },
    methods: {
      clickLink(link) {
        this.visible = false;
        if (link.click) {
          link.click();
        }
      },
      show() {
        this.visible = true;
      },

      refreshNodes() {
        if (this.visible) {
          this.breadcrumb = null;
          this.nodes = null;
         
  };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the props as `:main-link-groups` and `main-link-groups-two` but trying to access them as `mainLinkGroups` and `mainLinkGroupsTwo` respectively inside `ToolsMenu` component,
Do the below change and it might work

```
<tools-menu ref="toolsMenu" :mainLinkGroups="mainLinkGroups"/>
<tools-menu ref="toolsMenu" :mainLinkGroupsTwo="mainLinkGroupsTwo"/>
```

[Edited]
The braces are not correctly closed

```
computed: {
      mainLinkGroups() {
        return [
          {
            header: 'HeaderOne',
            icon: icons.HOME,
            links:   [
              {
                icon: 'fas fa-copy',
                text: 'Foo',
                area: 'ONE'
              }       
            ]
          } // Added Object closing
         ] // Added Array closing
      },
      mainLinkGroupsTwo() {
        return [
          {
            header: 'HeaderTwo',
            links:  [
              {
                to: '/home',
                icon: 'fas fa-home',
                text: 'home',
                area: 'TWO'
              },
            ]
         }
        ] // Added Array closing
    },
```

Also handle the empty array condition in the below code just in case

```
filteredLinkGroups() {
        if(!this.mainLinkGroups || (this.mainLinkGroups && !this.mainLinkGroups.length)) {
         return [];
        }
        return this.mainLinkGroups.map(linkGroup => ({header: linkGroup.header, links: linkGroup.links.filter(item => {
            const userAreaPermission = this.userAreaPermissionMap[item.area];
            return !item.area || userAreaPermission &&
              (item.modal ? userAreaPermission === 'FULL_CONTROL' : userAreaPermission !== 'NOT_ALLOWED');
          })}));
      },
      filteredLinkGroupsTwo() {
        if(!this.mainLinkGroupsTwo || (this.mainLinkGroupsTwo && !this.mainLinkGroupsTwo.length)) {
         return [];
        }
        return this.mainLinkGroupsTwo.map(linkGroup => ({header: linkGroup.header, links: linkGroup.links.filter(item => {
            const userAreaPermission = this.userAreaPermissionMap[item.area];
            return !item.area || userAreaPermission &&
                (item.modal ? userAreaPermission === 'FULL_CONTROL' : userAreaPermission !== 'NOT_ALLOWED');
          })}));
      },
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error. "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')". They work just fine if I only use mainLinkGroups or mainLinkGroupsTwo, but if I used them together I get the error.